# Xcode 4 final - breakpoints on device (ipad) not working

Tags: debugging, ipad, xcode4

I downloaded and installed final version of Xcode 4. I opened my iPad project and realised that breakpoint's doesn't work on the device. They work ok on simulator though.
Before I was using Xcode 3.2 and everything was working fine.

I also tried creating an empty view based iOS application from scratch and have exactly this same issue.  I was googling on that issue, but all solutions were based on previous versions of Xcode.
Any suggestions what am I doing wrong ?

Here is output from a console when running application

```
Mar 10 14:34:44 unknown installd[547] : entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Mar 10 14:34:44 unknown installd[547] : entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Mar 10 14:34:44 unknown SpringBoard[29] : Killing  me.device-debugging-test  activate:  deactivate:  for app installation
Mar 10 14:34:44 unknown installd[547] : entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Mar 10 14:34:44 unknown installd[547] : entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Mar 10 14:34:44 unknown SpringBoard[29] : Reloading application state for 'me.device-debugging-test' as its modification date has changed
Mar 10 14:34:45 unknown SpringBoard[29] : Reloading and rendering all application icons.
Mar 10 14:34:46 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[551] : debugserver-48 for armv6 Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Apple, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Mar 10 14:34:46 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[551] : Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Mar 10 14:34:47 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:me.device-debugging-test[0x4309]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
Mar 10 14:34:47 unknown com.apple.debugserver-48[551] : Got a connection, waiting for debugger instructions for task "(null)".
Mar 10 14:34:47 unknown kernel[0] : lockbot[544] Builtin profile: debugserver (sandbox)
Mar 10 14:34:47 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[552] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Mar 10 14:34:47 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[552] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/(...) [69] (sandbox)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reboot your device.

Short, sweet, and simple solution.
After hours spent digging through all the XCode options.

Comment: Wow it works!! :D I reinstalled Xcode4 and rebooted my Mac - it fixed Xcode crashing, than I rebooted my iPad and now debugging works fine. Thanks!

Comment: I've been wondering the answer to this ever since switching to XCode 4.  Breakpoints seem to sometimes work and at other times not.  :(  But, your answer worked for me too.  Thanks!  On another note, the breakpoints did work on the simulator, but I prefer running the app on the device.

Comment: I had the same issue since Xcode upgrade to 4.3, Simulator was hitting breakpoint but not the iPad. Reboot of iPad worked for me. True simple sweet and short solution.